# mvvm + live data, reloads the same fragment because of previous live data value

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

I have two fragments in single activity. On button click I set api json request body which causes api call. on api success response app moves to second fragment. but when i press back button fragment 2 reloads because of the previous live data success value.

observer is set to listen for api response

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.phoneNumberViewModel = phoneNumberViewModel
    pref = getSharedPref()
    setToolbar()
    setApiObservers()
    setClickListeners()
}
```

here trigerring api to load data from api or room

```
override fun onClick(view: View?) {
    activity?.let {
        if (isAdded) {
            when (view?.id) {
                R.id.btn_sign_in -> {
                    checkPhoneNumber(getString(R.string.msisdn_with_code, phoneNumberViewModel.msisdn.get().toString())) // here triggering api
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun checkPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: String) {
    phoneNumberViewModel.setCheckUserJSONBody(
        UserCheckJSONBody(
            getDeviceId(),
            phoneNumber,
            null
        )
    )
}

private fun setApiObservers() {
    setCheckUserApiObserver()
}
```

here it listens for api response

```
private fun setCheckUserApiObserver() {
    binding.userCheckDbTable = phoneNumberViewModel.userCheckDbTable
    phoneNumberViewModel.userCheckDbTable?.observe(
        viewLifecycleOwner,
        Observer { userCheckResponseResource ->
            activity?.let { fragActivity ->
                if (isAdded) {
                    userCheckResponseResource?.let { nonNullUserCheckResponseResource ->
                        when (nonNullUserCheckResponseResource.status) {
                            Status.LOADING -> {
                            }
                            Status.SUCCESS -> {
                                pref?.setValue(Constants.PHONE_NUMBER, getString(R.string.msisdn_with_code, phoneNumberViewModel.msisdn.get().toString()))
                                navigateToLoginPinFragment()
                            }
                            Status.MSISDN_NOT_REGISTERED -> {
                                navigateToCreatePinFragment()
                            }
                            Status.INTERNET_CONNECTION_ERROR -> {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    fragActivity,
                                    "internet connection error",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                ).show()
                            }
                            Status.INVALID_PARAMETERS -> {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    fragActivity,
                                    "invalid pramams",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                ).show()
                            }
                            else -> {
                                nonNullUserCheckResponseResource.data?.let { repeatNecTransactionResponse3 ->
                                    repeatNecTransactionResponse3.errorMessage?.let { errorMessage ->
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                            fragActivity,
                                            errorMessage,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                        ).show()
                                    } /*?: showMaintenanceErrorDialog()*/
                                } /*?: showMaintenanceErrorDialog()*/
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        })
}
```

Its decalared in view model like this:

```
 val userCheckDbTable: LiveData<Resource<UserCheckDBTable>>? =
    Transformations.switchMap(_fetchCheckUserJSONBody) { nonNullCheckUserJSONBody ->
        if (nonNullCheckUserJSONBody == null) {
            AbsentLiveData.create()
        } else {
            splashScreenRepository.callCheckUser(nonNullCheckUserJSONBody.getGson())
        }
    }
```

Comment: You must have a listener to move from Fragment1 to Fragment2 when API call is successful. Either unregister the listener after fragment transition or use a single time update method. Post the code for further clarifications

Comment: edited my question. you can check

Comment: What is "userCheckDbTable"? Give its datatype and where is it declared? (In ViewModel I suppose)

Comment: yes in view model